# Python Django: "Post.author" must be a "User" instance error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to assign username to author field in Post model ,  Django spews out the following error:

> "Post.author" must be a "User" instance.

model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='',null=True,blank=True)
image_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None,null=True,blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
content = models.TextField()
author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
published = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

view:

```
@login_required
def new_post(request):
   # Add a new post
   if request.method != 'POST':
      # No data submitted, create a blank form
      form = PostForm()
   else:
       # Post data submitted, process data
      form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         new_post = form.save(commit=False)
         new_post.author = request.user.username
         new_post.save()
         return redirect('elogs:posts')
   #Display a blank or invalid form
   context = {'form':form}
   return render(request,'elogs/new_post.html',context)
```

form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content','image','image_url','published']
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title..'}),
        'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'What is on your mind?'}),
        'categories': forms.TextInput()
        
    }
```

I have solved this error just like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
author = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the username instead of the user itself:

- `new_post.author = request.user.username`

A `ForeignKey` takes an instance of the given `Model`, `User` in this case.

Comment: i made this edit  new_post.author = request.user and i had  FOREIGN KEY constraint failed